# Code in html wont go under one of my div

Tags: html, css

After a lot of research on the subject i can't find where my problem is. I have a navigation bar and under an image that is set to absolute. When i write new code it does'nt take in consideration that there's an image and goes straight under my navigation bar even if in html it is written under the image.

Screenshot of my problem here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ZC7.jpg

I want the text to appear on the bottom of my page. Heres my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resto.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" id="ci-google-fonts-css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A400%2C400italic%2C700%7CAlegreya%3A700italic%2C400%2C400italic&amp;ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">


            <title>Restaurant</title>
        </head>


        <body>
           <div class="body">
               <div class="infohaut">
                  <p><a href="">Réserver dès maitenant | (418) 999-1350</a></p>
                    <div class="nav">
                        <div class="container">
                        <img src="logo-transparent_4.png" alt="">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Acceuil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Notre menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Notre mission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Nous contactez</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>




             <div class="image">
                <img src="coeur.png"/>
                <h2>Situé au coeur de la ville</h2>
                <p><a href="">Voir notre emplacement</a></p>
            </div>





             <div class="commentaire">
                 <h1>rftgere</h1> 
             </div>

        </body>   
</html>
```

Css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0 0;
    padding:0px;
}


    /* le main body du site */


body {
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.625;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
}

.body {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
    /* information en haut de la page */


.infohaut {
    background-color: rgb(88, 116, 152);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

.infohaut a {
    color: white;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.625;
    font-size:95%;
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    float: right;    
}

.infohaut a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.infohaut p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-shadow:0 0 2px #000000
}

    /* hover réservation */


.infohaut a:hover {
    color: #E86850;
    text-decoration: none;
}


    /* barre de navigation */


.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav img {
    width: 14%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    padding:25px 0px 25px 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid rgb(109, 109, 109);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
}

.container { 
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}


    /* hover des links dans la barre de navigation */


. nav a:link, nav a:visited {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;  
}


.nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #E86850;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}


    /* l'image fix */


.image img {
    width:100%;
    height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 147px;
  left: 0;
}

.image h2 {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: "Alegreya", "Georgia", serif;
    font-size: 62px;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
   text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px, #000000 -1px 1px, #000000 -1px -1px, #000000 1px -1px;

}

.image p {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 315px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.image a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
}


    /* hover pour lemplacement */


.image a:link, image a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;  
}


.image a:hover, image a:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}


/* Commentaire client */


.commentaire {
    position: absolute;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: because your height wasn't in maximum, little bit of content will get a result like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this will solve the issue. Just change your image class like this.

```
.image img {
 position:relative;
 left:0;
 height:400px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/claudios/bs0gunod/)

Comment: yepppppp, i got some reading to do on position see you later thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help. see you

Answer (score 0):

When you use the  "Absolute" attribute you need to define the distance from the top and left side of that division that is their container in pixels or percentage of screen size.
 I chose 250px as a starting point. You can adjust as needed. "Absolute" by itself does not define a position, only a position type. I added the z-index so it can move over other objects.

```
 /* Commentaire client */


.commentaire {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:100;
    top:250px;
    left:150px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: I get what you're saying but that's not my problem. My problem is why can 't this my div commentaire can't go below my div image. Like why does'nt it folow the html code?

Comment: Now I am confused. What do you mean by 'go below'? The code I gave you moved it down to the lower center of the image. If your talking about hiding your text below an image, then you need to use the z-index:-1; style. If it is stuck in place, then it needs a high z-index like z-index:100;.